# Non linear first DE with lot of parts

Tags: equation-solving, numerical-integration, boundary-conditions, education, generalized-function

I want to know how I can solve this equation in Mathematica I guess I missed something!!

DSolve[ {a (h[a])^2 h'[a] +(n*h[a]/ a^2) + m*(h[a])^3 - l (h[a])^2 - t == 0}, h, a]

h[a] is my function and n,m,l, and t are positive parameters.

Comment: Many DEs do not have symbolic solutions in terms of commonly defined functions. The nonlinear DE in the question probably falls in that category. However, it should be noted that `DSolve` sometimes is unable to solve DEs that do have symbolic solutions in terms of commonly defined functions.Try `NDSolve`?

Comment: I did with NDSolve but nothing happens

Comment: ClearAll["Global`*"]
NDSolve[ {a (h[a])^2 h'[a] - (n*h[a]/ a^2) - m*(h[a])^3 + 
    s (h[a]/a^2) - l (h[a])^2 - t == 0, h[a0] == 1}, h, {a, 0, 10}]

NDSolve::ndsv: Cannot find starting value for the variable h.

Comment: In order to solve your equation numerically with `NDSolve` you need to set *numerical* values for *all* parameters including a0.

Comment: `a0=0; ParametricNDSolve[{a*h[a]^2*h'[a]-n*h[a]/a^2-m*h[a]^3+s*h[a]/a^2-l*h[a]^2-t==0,h[a0]==1},h,{a,0,10},{n,m,s,l,t}]` But that may blow up because of your `a^2` in the denominators and your `a` ranges from 0 to 10

Comment: Can you supply values of constants?

Comment: Yes, the function h[a] doesn't have a=0 so you can consider a=0.01

Comment: So how to plot this ParametricNDSolve?

Comment: "So how to plot this?" Perhaps by reading the documentation https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ParametricNDSolve.html which includes four examples of plotting the solutions. But with five different parameters you are going to have to figure out if you need six or seven dimensional space to see your plot or whether you can give some fixed values for some of the parameters and look at the plot and then change some of the values, etc.